knit button error - '\U' backslash error Rstudio
I am taking the GDAC coursera class on R and I am getting this error specifically when pressing the "knit" button that creates an html/pdf/word file in Rstudio desktop.
 Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string (<input>:4:36) Execution halted 

After researching, I found a possible solution by creating a function for turning  '\' into '\\' or '/', in this post.
One reply lead me to a wordpath function of a R github package here.
I don't know how to implement a solution, but I have gone as far as creating the wp.r word-path package. I read the information provided by help(knit) on R studio, but I still am not how it operates.
I am a beginner in R and would like any level of information. Thank you!
#Here is my directory information
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Nguye/OneDrive/Documents/R"
> R.home()
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.0"
> path.expand("~")
[1] "C:/Users/Nguye/OneDrive/Documents"


If you have checked all code chunks in your current RMarkdown document for unescaped backslahes and replaced those with \\ or / and knit still complains, check your ~/.Rprofile  file for same issues, file.edit("~/.Rprofile")  . In Windows you'll most likely find it in your user's Documents folder.
